# How to map table name to a column on many to many relationship using EF6 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a database table that does not contain true foreign keys. It has two columns that reference the table name and the id of the record in that table. If it were a true foreign key then I could just create a [many to many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) and be on my way but this one has me stumped because of the table name dicriminator. Any help on how I can do this in the fluent API would be great!

[image]

Comment: I do not believe this is supported in EF. You will need to build your own logic for this I am afraid.

Comment: Are Table1 and Table2 one-to-one?

Comment: @JohnyL no it’s many-to-one. Table2 is used as a join table between Table1 and other tables in the database.